# "TypeError: Cannot pickle 'SSL Object' " When using concurrent.futuresProcessPoolExecutor() with IMAP

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, concurrent.futures, imaplib

I am using python 3.9 with IMAPlib in order to retrieve emails and scrape links from them. It works fine but can become quite slow for large amounts of emails (I'm doing ~40,000). In order to speed it up I'd like to use some concurrency I can get all the emails at once.

To do this I get the IDs of all the emails beforehand then assign each ID to a task in my pool. I close the previously used impalib connection before scrape_link_mp() is called. I have tried to use a lock and a manager lock but I still get the same error.

Am I missing something fundamental here? Let me know if anything else needs to be explained, thanks.

My code looks like this:

```
def scrape_link_mp(self):
    self.file_counter = 0
    self.login_session.logout()
    self.Manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
    self.lock = self.Manager.Lock()
    futures = []
            
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as Executor:    
        for self.num_message in self.arr_of_emails[self.start_index:]:
            task_params = self.current_user,self.current_password,self.counter,self.imap_url,self.num_message,self.substring_filter,self.link_regex,self.lock
            futures.append(
                Executor.submit(
                    self.scrape_link_from_email_single,
                    *task_params
                    )
                )
        for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures):
            self.counter+=1
            self.timestamp = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
            print(f'[{self.timestamp}] DONE: {self.counter}/{len(self.num_mails)}')
            print(future.result())

def scrape_link_from_email_single(self,current_user,current_password,counter,imap_url,num_message,substring_filter,link_regex,lock):
    login_session_mp.logout()
    current_user_mp = self.current_user
    current_password_mp = self.current_password
    self.lock.acquire()
    login_session_mp = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(self.imap_url,993)
    login_session_mp.login(current_user_mp,current_password_mp)
    self.search_mail_status, self.amount_matching_criteria = login_session_mp.search(Mail.CHARSET,search_criteria)
    _,individual_response_data = login_session_mp.fetch(self.num_message,'(RFC822)')
    self.lock().release
    
    raw = email.message_from_bytes(individual_response_data[0][1])
    scraped_email_value = str(email.message_from_bytes(Mail.scrape_email(raw)))
    print(scraped_email_value)
    returned_links = str(link_regex.findall(scraped_email_value))
    for i in returned_links:
        if substring_filter:
            self.lock.acquire()            
            with open('out.txt','a+') as link_file:
                link_file.write(i +'\n')
                link_file.close()
            self.lock.release()
```